# twitteR package error

Tags: r, twitter

I'm using new version of twitteR package downloaded on Jeoff Gentry and I'm connecting on Twitter through `setup_twitter_oauth()` function. When I call the function I get:

```
Error: Deprecated: supply token object to config directly
```

I defined my keys in code and used this function:

```
setup_twitter_oauth(consumerKey, consumerSecret, accessToken, accessSecret, credentials_file = NULL)
```

Comment: I think this is the old way to connect with Twitter API. Look at Jeoff's github and you'll see that he is using this way to connect.

Comment: From the twitteR mailinglist: *I sent an email to the list about this on Friday: http://lists.hexdump.org/pipermail/twitter-users-hexdump.org/2014-February/000542.html I was unable to get things working, needed more information from Hadley. Hopefully I'll get some time tonight to get it at least functional.*

Answer (score 0):

I struggled with this issue, too. What worked for me was to go to register a new app under your account at https://apps.twitter.com/. I was then able to go through the `setup_twitter_oauth` command again. An example *after you create a new app, as stated above*:

```
consumer_key <- “your_consumer_key”
consumer_secret <- “your_consumer_secret”
access_token <- “your_access_token”
access_secret <- “your_access_secret”
setup_twitter_oauth(consumer_key, consumer_secret, access_token, access_secret)
```

Do make sure that you have already created an access token.